# Xorg: integrated video as primary display & nvidia headless

Tags: linux, nvidia, gnome, xorg

My computer has an integrated Intel graphics and an RTX 2070 Super GPU. Until I reinstalled Fedora I was able to use the Intel card as main video display and the RTX only for machine learning.

This time, after installing all drivers and setting up xorg.conf as previously, although the HDMI cable is connected to the Intel output, it seems that xorg is running on the Nvidia GPU.

This is the output of **lspci**:

```
[edu@localhost ~]$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 [GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER] (rev a1)
```

This is the output of **nvidia-smi**:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.50       Driver Version: 430.50       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 207...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 25%   34C    P0    31W / 215W |    329MiB /  7982MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1535      G   /usr/libexec/Xorg                             27MiB |
|    0      1705      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          51MiB |
|    0      2037      G   /usr/libexec/Xorg                             68MiB |
|    0      2173      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         179MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It looks weird, I have duplicated Xorg and gnome-shell processes. I can kill the first two but if I kill the last two my gnome session is killed. And I remember that on last installation I only had 2 process runing.

I can still run TensorFlow on GPU, it's all good, but when the GPU is under load my desktop will lag.

This is my **xorg.conf**:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "intel"
    Screen      1  "nvidia"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "intel"
    Driver         "intel"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Option         "AccelMethod"  "SNA"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "nvidia"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "intel"
    Device         "intel"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "nvidia"
    Device         "nvidia"
    Option         "Coolbits" "4"
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"  "on"
    Option         "IgnoreDisplayDevice"  "CRT"
EndSection
```

I don't really understand what is going on or how to investigate, but I'm very sure that xserver *(or should I call it xorg?)* is not running on my Intel but on my Nvidia and I need to make it the other way.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Wrong Bus ID for the Intel device!